# easy way of running different groups of Cypress tests

Tags: cypress

So I have a project dir under that I have my Cypress dir under that I have two dir's with different tests I run. Right now in my project dir I have a cypress.json that has the setting "integrationFolder": "cypress/test_tests",when I issue the command npx cypress run it gets the dir from the integrationFolder setting in the .json file but if I want to run the tests from a different dir I have to edit the cypress.json file and set the integrationFolder to the other dir, is there a way I can specify which dir I want Cypress to pick the tests from?

Comment: The docs are not very good, but I believe `cypress run --config integrationFolder=myOtherFolder` is the syntax you need to try out, experiment with.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as explained [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line#cypress-run-spec-lt-spec-gt)

```
cypress run --spec 'tests/folderOne/**/*'
```

or

```
cypress run --spec 'tests/folderTwo/**/*'
```

Answer (score 1):

Added config into your cypress.json

`"integrationFolder": "./",`

then both your folders can be supported by Cypress runner.

To run them you can add the commands in package.json:

`"cypress-test1": "cypress run --spec \"cypress/folder1/*.spec.js\""`

`"cypress-test2": "cypress run --spec \"cypress/folder2/*.spec.js\""`

so you can run either folder by a short command, like:

`yarn cypress-test1`